# wordpress wp_localize_script not working js var undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I 'm trying to get a php value inside my jquery file but i get undefined var in js console. I tried add wp_enqueue_script but the same result. This is my code:

```js
function render_product_basic_metabox( $post ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adminready', plugins_url()."/$plugin_folder/js/adminready.js", array()); 
    $curs = "";
    wp_localize_script('adminready', 'mysettings', array('currenciesRole' => $curs)); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'render_product_basic_metabox' );
?>
```

Comment: can you add the js code? (At least the lines where you want to use the data)

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 bindRoleChosen (mysettings);
});

Comment: You can edit the post to add the code. Anyway, I'm not sure what "bindRoleChosen" does, but you should change `mysettings` to `mysettings.currenciesRole`

Comment: i'm using mysettings.currenciesRole inside bindRoleChosen

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in JS file uri

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'adminready', plugins_url()."/$plugin_folder/js/adminready.js", array());
```

Wrong here /$plugin_folder/

First you must check the file url and the file has been called on the page using inspect or firebug

Comment: I used that $plugin_folder = $GLOBALS['plugin_folder']; at the beginning of my function but not working

Comment: Use it like this $plugin_folder = $GLOBALS['plugin_folder'];
wp_enqueue_script( 'adminready', $plugin_folder."/js/adminready.js", array());

Comment: even like this not working I also added add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'render_product_basic_metabox' ); after closure of the function.  Do you think it can be the fact to use wp_localize inside the function which can be the problem?